# Add image file using cakephp and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.2

I'm new user on mongodb, I'm working with cakephp. I'm trying to test the cakephp's plugin from ichikaway. This plugin allow cakephp working with a mongodb (NoSql database). So, I'm wondering if someone have already tried to do an image upload with ?

Comment: Sorry can't see the question here? What have you tried and what difficulty is it that you are having?

Comment: This is what I do in the case of Sql database:

Comment: So basically how to save an image in a database? This question has been asked many times and there are whole debates on this site alone about the issue.

Comment: You have asked this question many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919616/add-a-image-file-in-mongodb-using-cakephp but maybe @DanielCasserly can link some of those questions for you to look at, I mjust admit I have trouble finding these "many" questions.

Answer (score 0):

The [cakephp-mongodb](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) library does not seem to provide an API for interacting with [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS). Your best bet is likely to use the [MongodbSource::getMongoDb()](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/master/models/datasources/mongodb_source.php#L286) method to obtain the [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) instance and then access the [MongoGridFS](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php) classes directly. The PHP documentation includes several examples for storing files (including uploaded files) to GridFS.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works !

```
     <?php

      class ProductsController extends AppController {
       public $name = 'Products';


       public function add(){
      if ($this->request->is('post')){
        debug($this->request->data);
        $dir = IMAGES.date('Y');
        if (!file_exists($dir))
            mkdir($dir);
        $dir .= DS.date('m');
        if (!file_exists($dir))
            mkdir($dir);
        $f = explode('.', $this->request->data['Product']['file']['name']);
        $ext = '.'.end($f);
        $filename = Inflector::slug(implode('.',array_slice($f,0,-1)),'-');
        debug($ext);
        debug($filename);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->request->data['Product']['name'],
            'url' => date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.$filename.$ext
            );
        //debug($data);
        if ($this->Product->save($data)){
            move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Product']['file']['tmp_name'], $dir.DS.$filename.$ext);
            $id = $this->Product->getInsertId();
            debug($id);
        }
    }
}
```